# Wordpress duplication of URL using css accordion

Tags: css, wordpress, url-rewriting

Im a newbie Wordpress developer and I have been trying to find a solution to this where possible.

The problem: I am using a css accordion for my categories pages to display different posts. The problem with this is that the "the_permalink();" aspect of wordpress seems to be the only way to display the post and this causes a duplication in the url after the # (hash) which outputs http://www.mydomain.com/category#http://www.mydomain.com/postname. What I would like to do is have the output http://www.mydomain.com/category#postname displayed, if possible. Would this require url rewriting or is there a way to get a cleaner output without having to use rewrites?

My code at the moment:

`<div class="accordion vertical">
    <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=category-name&posts_per_page=10&orderby=date&order=asc' );
        while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();?>
        <section id="<?php the_permalink();?><?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
            <h2><a href="#<?php the_permalink();?><?php echo $post->post_name;?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </section>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if you removed the anchor tag within the  tag? The [accordion jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) function should add its own link to make it work properly